# Enforced pattern order

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I'm writing a Magic The Gathering (MTG) game engine in Haskell.

For those unfamiliar with MTG, it's a card game where cards can have up to 5 colors: White (W), Blue (U), Black (B), Red (R), and Green (G).

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
import Data.Set

data Color = W | U | B | R | G
    deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

data Card = Card (Set Color) -- simplified Card type with only its colors

viewColors :: Card -> [Color]
viewColors (Card colors) = toList colors
```

---

What I would like to do is pattern match on colors like so:

```
foo :: Card -> String
foo (viewColors -> [W, B]) = "card is white and black"
foo _ = "whatever"
```

So far, so good. But there is one problem here: I can type the order of colors incorrectly in the view pattern like so:

```
bar :: Card -> String
bar (viewColors -> [B, W]) = "this will never get hit"
bar _ = "whatever"
```

Of course, I could have written `viewColors` in a way that directly resolves this problem. Or I could use guards, but I'd rather not. Here are a couple ways to do so

```
viewColors :: Card -> (Bool, Bool, Bool, Bool, Bool)
viewColors (Card colors) = let m = (`member` colors)
    in (m W, m U, m B, m R, m G)
```

This solution is overly verbose while pattern matching, even if I use a type isomorphic to `Bool` but with shorter (and/or meaningful) identifiers. Matching a Green card would look like

```
baz :: Card -> String
baz (viewColors -> (False, False, False, False, True)) = "it's green"
```

---

```
data ColorView = W | WU | WUB | ... all combos here

viewColors :: Card -> ColorView
viewColors (Card colors) = extract correct Colorview from colors
```

This solution has combinatorial explosion. Seems extremely bad to implement, but nice to use, especially if I have a `colorViewToList :: ColorView -> [Color]` to allow programmatic extraction after the pattern match.

---

I have no idea if the following can be approximated in Haskell, but the following would be ideal:

```
fuz :: Card -> String
fuz (viewColors -> (W :* ())) = "it's white"
fuz (viewColors -> (W :* U :* ())) = "it's white and blue"
fuz (viewColors -> (W :* B :* ())) = "it's white and black"
```

---

I'm willing to use advanced language extensions to allow this kind of code: DataKinds, PolyKinds, TypeFamilies, MultiParamTypeClasses, GADTs, you name it.

Is something like this possible? Do you have other suggested approaches?

Comment: Why not use guards? A guard would be almost as pretty as the view pattern: `f card | card `color` [B, W] = ... | card `color` [B,U,W] = ...`. Also, this sounds like a cool project; what are you planning to do with it?

Comment: You may want to check [this](https://github.com/MedeaMelana/Magic) out.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis: I'm not allergic to guards... they are clean and easy. It's just that I love pattern matching a whole lot more. Also, learning the theory is interesting in and of itself.

Comment: @PaulVisschers: Thanks for the link. I was surprised to find the same link when googling "Haskell mtg" the other day. Definitely something I'd like to browse, though I believe I'm going to take a radically different approach to my engine (same goes for other open source Magic programs).

Comment: `OverloadedLists` would help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the record solution, but it is easy to do with typeclasses

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import qualified Data.Set as Set

data Color = W' | U' | B' | R' | G' deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
data Card = Card (Set.Set Color) 

newtype W a = W a
newtype U a = U a
newtype B a = B a
newtype R a = R a
newtype G a = G a

class ToColors x where
  toColors :: x -> [Color]
  reify :: x

instance ToColors () where
  toColors _ = []
  reify = ()

instance ToColors a => ToColors (W a) where
  toColors (W a) = W':toColors a
  reify = W reify

--other instances

members :: Set.Set Color -> [Color] -> Bool
members s = foldl (\b e -> b && (Set.member e s)) True

viewColors :: forall a. ToColors a => Card -> Maybe a
viewColors (Card s) = let a = reify :: a in 
  if members s (toColors a) then (Just a) else Nothing

foo :: Card -> String
foo (viewColors -> Just (W (B ()))) = "card is white and black"
foo _ = "whatever"
```

this could easily be reworked to get other syntaxes.  Like, you could define the colors to be types that don't take parameters, and then use an infix heterogeneous list constructor.  Either way it does not care about order.

Edit: if you want to match exact sets that is easy also--just replace the `members` function like so

```
viewColors :: forall a. ToColors a => Card -> Maybe a
viewColors (Card s) = let a = reify :: a in 
  if s == (Set.fromList . toColors $ a) then (Just a) else Nothing
```

Comment: Awesome, this satisfies my wants exactly. That said, ScopedTypeVariables is completely unneeded to get this to compile ;) (Well at least if monomorphism restriction is not disabled.)

Comment: @ThomasEding.  I should have thought of that.  You can also get it to typecheck even with `NoMonomorphismRestriction` enabled if you use abstraction instead of `let` to avoid generalization `viewColors (Card s) = flip ($) reify (\a -> if s == (Set.fromList . toColors $ a) then (Just a) else Nothing)` has the infered type `viewColors :: ToColors a => Card -> Maybe a` which is exactly what you want

Comment: @ThomasEding This solution has same power as "record solution". 
`Just (W (B ())))` is both `[W',B',U']` and `[W',B']`, but not `[W']`

Answer (score 4):

Main problem is you wish to have permutation instead single value from `view`. We have only one type which allow permutation - record.

So, we can add new data, record type

```
data B = F|T -- just shorter name for Bool in patterns
data Palette = P {isW, isU, isB, isR, isG :: B}

bool2b :: Bool -> B
bool2b True  = T
bool2b False = F

viewColors :: Card -> Palette
viewColors (Card colors) = let m = bool2b . (`member` colors)
    in P {isW = m W, isU = m U, isB = m B, isR = m R, isG = m G}

foo :: Card -> String
foo (viewColors -> P {isW=T, isB=T}) = "card is white and black"
foo _ = "whatever"
```

---

**UPDATED**

We also could **deny** wrong patterns. But this solution is more ugly, but it allow use "classic" patterns

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
data Color = W | U | B | R | G  deriving (Eq)

data W' 
data U' 
data B'
data R'
data G'

data Color' a where
      W' :: Color' W'
      U' :: Color' U'
      B' :: Color' B'
      R' :: Color' R'
      G' :: Color' G'

data M a = N | J a -- just shorter name for Maybe a in patterns

data Palette = Palette 
      (M (Color' W')) 
      (M (Color' U')) 
      (M (Color' B')) 
      (M (Color' R')) 
      (M (Color' G'))
```

and define `viewColor`:

```
viewColors :: Card -> Palette
viewColors (Card colors) = 
  let 
    m :: Color -> Color' a -> M (Color' a)
    m c e = if c `member` colors then J e else N
  in P (m W W') (m U U') (m B B') (m R R') (m G G')

foo :: Card -> String
foo (viewColors -> Palette (J W') N (J B') N N) = 
      "card is white and black"
foo _ = "whatever"
```

Comment: Nice solution, but is there a way to make it for a card with colors WUB to not match `foo (viewColors -> P { isW=T })`? Regardless, this is useful to at least query part of a card's colors.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: Further testing shows that this solution does not actually work.

---

You actually don't need any more extensions, I came up with a solution that does what you want, but you'll probably want to optimize it, rename some things, and make it a bit less ugly.  You just need to make a new data type and implement `Eq` yourself and make the operator use `infixr`:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
import Data.Set

data Color = W | U | B | R | G
    deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

data Card = Card (Set Color) -- simplified Card type with only its colors

-- you may need to fiddle with the precedence here
infixr 0 :*
data MyList a = END | a :* (MyList a) deriving (Show)

myFromList :: [a] -> MyList a
myFromList [] = END
myFromList (x:xs) = x :* myFromList xs

instance Eq a => Eq (MyList a) where
    END == END = True
    END == _   = False
    _   == END = False
    l1  == l2  = allElem l1 l2 && allElem l2 l1
        where
            -- optimize this, otherwise it'll just be really slow
            -- I was just too lazy to write it correctly
            elemMyList :: Eq a => a -> MyList a -> Bool
            elemMyList a ml = case ml of
                END -> False
                (h :* rest) -> if a == h then True else elemMyList a rest
            allElem :: Eq a => MyList a -> MyList a -> Bool
            allElem END l = True
            allElem (h :* rest) l = h `elemMyList` l && allElem rest l

viewColors :: Card -> MyList Color
viewColors (Card colors) = myFromList $ toList colors

fuz :: Card -> String
fuz (viewColors -> (W :* END)) = "it's white"
fuz (viewColors -> (W :* U :* END)) = "it's white and blue"
fuz (viewColors -> (W :* B :* END)) = "it's white and black"
fuz (viewColors -> (W :* B :* R :* END)) = "it's white, black, and red"
fuz (viewColors -> (W :* U :* B :* R :* G :* END)) = "it's all colors"
fuz _ = "I don't know all my colors"

main = do
    putStrLn $ fuz $ Card $ fromList [W, B]
    putStrLn $ fuz $ Card $ fromList [B, W]
```

---

EDIT: Just fixed the code a bit

Comment: Another similar solution would be to convert each `MyList a` into `[a]`, sort, then just use `==`.  That would probably be fewer lines of easier to read code.  However, I wrote this rather quickly, so there's definite room for improvement.

Comment: This solution doesn't exactly work either. For example, if I write the WU case as `(U :* W :* END)` and change the `main` card colors to `[W, U]` and `[U, W]` I get "I don't know all my colors" for both. That said, your comment inspired me to write a view pattern for a match, which I would be happy with: `fuz (matchColors [W, U] -> True) = blah` where `matchColors` can massage the input to work regardless of the written order.

Comment: @ThomasEding Huh, strange, I'll just say that I wrote this code rather quickly and didn't do much testing with it, but the basics are there to get what you want.  However, if you're just going to use `matchColors`, then you might as well just use guards, it'd be cleaner code that way too.

Comment: Yeah. More or a curiosity than anything. I'll probably end up doing the obvious (guards), but I'm still going to tinker around with my original problem to learn something new.

Comment: I don't know much about `ViewPatterns`, so I checked the output from `ghc --make -ddump-simpl code.hs` and quickly saw that it converts it into pattern matching with a case statement, so I don't think there even a possibility that it'd work how you'd like it.  You can try playing around with it a bit more, but I don't think what you want is truly possible.  It seems that my testing earlier might have just been a fluke, because it doesn't use the `Eq` instance at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should focus on expressing precisely what a card's colors can be first, and then worry about other concerns like making things terse later. It sounds to me like your `Bool` tuple solution is almost perfect, however I'm guessing that a card *must* have one color, correct?

In that case something like this might work, and be pretty easy to pattern match:

```
data CardColors = W' BlackBool GreenBool ...
                | B' WhiteBool GreenBool ...
                | G' BlackBool WhiteBool ...
                ....

data BlackBool = B 
               | NotB
-- etc.
```

You can create a heterogeneous list with a defined order fairly easily, but I don't think that kind of polymorphism will serve you here.

Comment: Cards are allowed to be colorless in Magic. Regardless of the practicality of my original question, I'd still be fascinated with a working technique just to learn how it's done. Though now I'm thinking that some sort of type-class written in a way like how a type-safe printf in Haskell would work, though I would be unable to try out such code today.

Answer (score 0):

(Not an answer to your question, but hopefully a solution to your problem!)

I would go with the dumbest thing that could possibly work:

```
is :: Card -> Color -> Bool
is card col = col `elem` (viewColors card) -- can be optimized to use the proper elem!
```

and then

```
foo :: Card -> String
foo c
    | c `is` B && c `is` W = "card is black and white"
    | c `is` R || c `is` G = "card is red or green"
    | otherwise = "whatever"
```

If spelling the whole list out to check whether a card has all 5 colors is too long, then you could define extra combinators like

```
hasColors :: Card -> [Color] -> Bool
hasColors card = all (`elem` (viewColors card))
```

Is there a reason this is not acceptable?

Comment: The main reason I don't use guards that often is that I strongly prefer case expressions over pattern matching over multiple definitions. Using guards is annoying in these cases (no pun intended) in that I think writing `case () of _ | x == 1 -> 1; _ | x == 2 -> 2 ; ...` is ugly (done when nested under "actual" pattern matching case expressions of course). That said I just read about the MultiWayIf extension, which would de-uglify this kind of code.